# How to resize a JFile Chooser

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser, file-browser

I am designing a file browser using Java Swing, and here is what I have so far:

[image]

I have a JFileChooser in a panel, however it stays the same size when I reshape the window.
However, I want to make it look like this:

[image: Without the items inside resizing of course.]

Is it possible to make the actual Browser box resize along with the form?

EDIT: I do not want a popup JFileChooser, the JFileChooser is INSIDE the Frame.

Comment: Try adding the file chooser panel to a panel using a BorderLayout. Then hopefully the components will resize as you size the frame. If you just add the file chooser to a panel it will retain its preferred size because by default a panel uses a FlowLayout. Post your `SSCCE` that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: @camickr: that should probably be an answer, not a comment since it describes the problem and gives the correct solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to add the file chooser to a panel - if you just initialize one and set it visible, it will automatically be resizable.

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
chooser.setVisible(true);
int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    //continue your code here
```

---

To incorporate the file chooser into the panel, try this:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
panel.add(chooser);
frame.add(panel);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

I'm not sure how you used the BorderLayout before but this code works perfectly on my computer.

Comment: The JFileChooser has to be inside the form, not a dialog. I'll edit it into the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you just add the file chooser panel to a panel it will retain its preferred size because by default a panel uses a FlowLayout.

Try adding the file chooser panel to the `CENTER` of  a panel using a `BorderLayout`. Then hopefully the components will resize as you size the frame (assuming the file chooser panel uses appropriate layout managers).

Comment: I used the BorderLayout, but it did nothing.

Comment: @TheRyan722, as I suggested in my original comment, post your `SSCCE` that demonstrates the problem.